# List data inside another list in RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have got a list (in JSON format): `questionList`. I am printing all its objects using a `RecyclerView`. Inside that there is `ChildQuestionList`. I want to print that too for every single object of `questionList`. How do I do that? The adapter runs a single time and prints `questionList` 0th object data. There is a list of data inside that. Without making the adapter run again, how could it be possible to print that list. The data is question/answer type and it's dynamic.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Please clarify using one or two short sentences for each: 1. What is your specific goal? 2. What is the exact problem you are having? After stating those things clearly, go into more detail in following paragraphs, best with code examples of what you currently have. That would help us help you. :)

Comment: @mike.bronner I think, I understood his question.  He wants to have list of main questions and subquestions under main questions. I gave answer to it below. I think that's what he wants.

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your question to attempt to clarify it, adding some formatting which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You've already gotten some answers, so that's great... but in the future, I think you're going to receive help much more readily if you provide some code rather than attempt to describe it. This will allow most developers to see at a glance what you were attempting and provide a solution. Cheers!

Comment: @mike.bronner..okay i will add the code..

Comment: @RichChurcher... thanks buddy for your effort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do it with one Adapter, and one list of all questions - both Main and Child questions. Make questions extend from one type (SuperQuestion) and push to ArrayList list and draw with adapter, based on type of the question with correct layout.

In adapter you should have two types of ViewHolders - Main and Child. And you will draw two types of questions. Just make sure you order them correctly

[tutorial one](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e)

[tutorial two](https://ode.hopmarket.com/understanding-recyclerview-viewtypes-3fe4865da357)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yaa...the answer is correct by requirement was bit different.next time i will add my code in the question.anyway thanks